# How to use the JRE bundled in a JavaFX 2 self-contained application to start a runnable JAR on Mac OS X?

Tags: javafx-2, java

I created a JavaFX 2 self-contained application for Mac OS X.  It works fine.
Inside the application bundle (.app), there's a PlugIns directory and inside the PlugIns directory there's a directory that contains the JRE.
How can I use that JRE to launch another Runnable Jar?
I look inside the JRE directory, but I can't find a java executable binary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include java.exe in the runtime built](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669122/include-java-exe-in-the-runtime-built)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the generated binary in your MacOS-Folder bootstraps java by using the libjvm.dylib directly. You could try copying the java-binary from your java installation into a folder bin next to jre

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1307236:

Each self-contained application package includes the following:

- A private copy of the Java and JavaFX Runtimes, to be used by this application only

So it appears that by design you are not supposed to be able to use that JRE with any other application. But I am not aware of what checks are in place to enforce this.